# How to make threadsafe an asynchronous matrix multiplication with c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, matrix, future

I'm trying to write a parallel divide and conquer algorithm for matrix multiplication where the matrices are 2^N x 2^n. My solution works fine for smaller matrices, but when i try to multiply two 2^6 x 2^6 or bigger matrices it starts to write random 0s, and badly calculated results.
I think the problem is that too many threads start on that size maybe, but i can't figure out since a day how to solve it. Thanks for any help.
Here's my attempt so far:

```
bool ParallelMultiply(const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &m1, const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &m2, std::vector<std::vector<int> > &dest)
{
if((m1.size() == 1) && m1.size() == m1[0].size())
    dest[0][0] = m1[0][0]*m2[0][0];
else
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > temp(m1.size());
    for(int i=0; i < temp.size(); i++)
        temp[i].resize(temp.size());

    int subSize = m1.size()/2;

    std::vector<std::vector<int> > A11 = SubMatrix(m1, 0, 0);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > A12 = SubMatrix(m1, 0, subSize);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > A21 = SubMatrix(m1, subSize, 0);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > A22 = SubMatrix(m1, subSize, subSize);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > B11 = SubMatrix(m2, 0, 0);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > B12 = SubMatrix(m2, 0, subSize);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > B21 = SubMatrix(m2, subSize, 0);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > B22 = SubMatrix(m2, subSize, subSize);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > dest11 = SubMatrix(dest, 0, 0);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > dest12 = SubMatrix(dest, 0, subSize);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > dest21 = SubMatrix(dest, subSize, 0);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > dest22 = SubMatrix(dest, subSize, subSize);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > temp11 = SubMatrix(temp, 0, 0);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > temp12 = SubMatrix(temp, 0, subSize);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > temp21 = SubMatrix(temp, subSize, 0);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > temp22 = SubMatrix(temp, subSize, subSize);


    std::future<bool> f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, ParallelMultiply, std::cref(A11), std::cref(B11), std::ref(dest11));
    std::future<bool> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, ParallelMultiply, std::cref(A12), std::cref(B21), std::ref(temp11));

    std::future<bool> f3 = std::async(std::launch::async, ParallelMultiply, std::cref(A11), std::cref(B12), std::ref(dest12));
    std::future<bool> f4 = std::async(std::launch::async, ParallelMultiply, std::cref(A12), std::cref(B22), std::ref(temp12));


    std::future<bool> f5 = std::async(std::launch::async, ParallelMultiply, std::cref(A21), std::cref(B11), std::ref(dest21));
    std::future<bool> f6 = std::async(std::launch::async, ParallelMultiply, std::cref(A22), std::cref(B21), std::ref(temp21));

    std::future<bool> f7 = std::async(std::launch::async, ParallelMultiply, std::cref(A21), std::cref(B12), std::ref(dest22));
    std::future<bool> f8 = std::async(std::launch::async, ParallelMultiply, std::cref(A22), std::cref(B22), std::ref(temp22));

    f1.wait(); f2.wait(); f3.wait(); f4.wait(); f5.wait(); f6.wait(); f7.wait(); f8.wait();

    AddMatrices(temp11, dest11);
    AddMatrices(temp12, dest12);
    AddMatrices(temp21, dest21);
    AddMatrices(temp22, dest22);

    MergeMatrices(dest11, dest12, dest21, dest22, dest);

}

return true;
}
```

The other two functions:

```
void AddMatrices(const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &m, std::vector<std::vector<int> > &res)
{
for(int i=0; i < m.size(); i++)
    for(int j=0; j < m.size(); j++)
        res[i][j] += m[i][j];
}

void MergeMatrices(const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &m1, const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &m2, const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &m3, const std::vector<std::vector<int> > &m4, std::vector<std::vector<int> > &res)
{
int x = res.size()/2;
for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<x; j++)
    {
        res[i][j] = m1[i][j];
        res[i][x+j] = m2[i][j];
        res[x+i][j] = m3[i][j];
        res[x+i][x+j] = m4[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified your logic in SubMatrix, AddMatrices and MergeMatrices? You are creating a very high number of vector copies, so this code is extremely inefficient (except for the fact that you perform the naive definition of the matrix multiplication), but I don't see obvious errors. A bit curious though on the case N != n.

Comment: N = n always, just mistyped. And i add the the other 2 functions, i think they're both works good.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal wirking example?

Comment: I read the 2 matrices from a .txt into vector<vector>> matrix1 and matrix2 in main(). Declare another one for the result. Using it like: ParallelMultiply(matrix1, matrix2, result); If i read smaller matrices it works good, but for big inputs it produces the mentioned problem.

Comment: Well i solved it, but i'm not sure how, so i don't write it as an answer. The differences i made was that i used a vector<future<bool>> for containing the futures. And after that i used MergeMatrix twice to get the temp and dest matrices, which i then Added to eachother.

Comment: std::launch_async policy might raise a very large number of threads in recursion, you might wish to check on the resources the function is taking.

Comment: Ya gotta stop copying immutable data.  You need to operate on views of the source matrixes, not copies.  Once you have a `matrix_view` type, you can add `drop_top(N)` and `keep_top(N)` and `drop_left(N)` and `keep_left(N)` methods, which gets rid of your power-of-2 pain.  Instead of breaking things into 4 each time, try breaking them into 2 along the longest axis.  Now your recursion gets much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the optimazation tips, especially for the suggestion of using a view-class! Breaking the matrices into 4 was a pre-specified criterium, this is a "homework". If my hands were free i think i'd have tried to use Strassen's algorithm.

Comment: Why do you create submatrices out of `dest` and `temp`? You are not using any of the values.

Comment: Because i tried to follow this algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm#Shared-memory_parallelism

Comment: The algorithm in the Wikipedia doesn't have anything like `MergeMatrices`, but your code does. This is an expensive operation. Creating submatrices in your version is expensive too. If you don't care about efficiency that's fine, but if you do, perhaps you should think again about how to implement the partition thing correctly.

Comment: Point was taken already, but thanks to make it clear! :) I've realized the problem from Yakk's comment.